# React Native adjustsFontSizeToFit - behaving oddly when combined with panResponder (ios)

Tags: ios, react-native, gesture, react-native-ios

To preface, I'm attempting to make a resizable Text component, which allows the user to resize the height/width by dragging. The resizing works as expected. My issue is with automatically adjusting the fontSize to fit the component dimensions.

I'm using the adjustsFontSizeToFit prop, which works, but not without some odd behavior. Essentially, as the user drags, and the text grows/shrinks, it will occasionally "hide" the last letter of the text. If you drag slightly further, the last letter will then appear again. In case that's not clear, here is a picture of the issue...

Starting position:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cta1r.png

Second Position:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LAqu.png

Final Position:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayNYz.png

I've been desperately looking for an answer and trying different solutions, but nothing seems to work. I don't understand what could be causing the issue, but as best I can surmise, it seems like the font just doesn't adjust quickly enough, so it causes the final letter to be clipped. My reasoning for this thought, is that the disappearing doesn't happen once the fontSize reaches its maximum value. This issue just doesn't make, though, since the font definitely has room to fit the final letter.

Anyway, it's been almost a week of banging my head against the wall, so I'm really hoping someone out there can shed some light on this issue. The only workaround I see is to code out my own fontSize adjustment, but that seems ridiculous, considering React Native has a prop for that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

edit... I forgot to mention that I have found one solution to remove the disappearing letter. That solution is to remove height from the style and replace it with lineHeight. This creates a different issue, however, which is that the fontSize no longer adjusts to the height of the component, meaning the font will sometimes be larger than the component, leading it to be cut off.